# How to use getChildContext with functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, redux

I want to pass some props down the tree via context from a functional component
that is almost on the top of the app. Is there a way to achieve this, or should we declare instead a ES6 / `createClass` react component?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

You can't pass context to children using functional components

Answer (score 2):

Define the contextTypes as you would normally do:

```
const Hello = (props, context) => <div>{context.name}</div>;
Hello.contextTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

A fiddle is available: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/55601/.

Comment: I meant to pass them down the tree via context

Comment: Ohh, I got the question wrongly. Functional component is at the top of the tree? Surprised.

Comment: I am refactoring now for performance reasons. Some functional components now are candidates to be connected to the `store`. Sorry for the confusion.